# Is it possible to paint a part of an panel with a different Colour?

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

[Image for better understanding: This Polygon should be in another colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdNNd.jpg) I'm new into programming but i made a good progress in the last weeks.
I've writen an application for calculating the second moment of an area.
You are able to select points for a n-Polygon and they will be drawn in a Panel.
For aesthetic reasons i want the Polygon to be in another Colour than the background.
Is there a away to make this ?
It is a hypothetical question so i cant put any code of it yet.
Thanks for your help

Code :
for context vecPolygons has one or more Polygon safed and the belonging points

```
 public void AppendNewPolygon()
        {
            double[][,] vecTemp;
            vecTemp = vecPolygons;                         
            
            int i;
            vecPolygons = new double[vecTemp.Length + 1][,];     
            
            for( i=0; i< vecTemp.Length; i++)                   
            {
                vecPolygons[i] = vecTemp[i];
            }
            vecPolygons[vecTemp.Length] = new double[0, 2];         

        }
```

```
public void AppendNewPointBefore()
        {
            double[,] arrTemp;
            int i;

            if (vecPolygons.GetLength(0) > 0) 
            {
                arrTemp = vecPolygons[activePolygon];

                vecPolygons[activePolygon] = new double[arrTemp.GetLength(0) + 1, 2];


                for (i = 0; i < activePoint; i++)
                {
                    vecPolygons[activePolygon][i, 0] = arrTemp[i, 0];
                    vecPolygons[activePolygon][i, 1] = arrTemp[i, 1];
                }

                vecPolygons[activePolygon][activePoint, 0] = 0;
                vecPolygons[activePolygon][activePoint, 1] = 0;


                for (i = activePoint; i < arrTemp.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    vecPolygons[activePolygon][i + 1, 0] = arrTemp[i, 0];
                    vecPolygons[activePolygon][i + 1, 1] = arrTemp[i, 1];
                }
            } 
        }
```

Paint command for the Panel named pGraphic

```
private void pGraphic_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            pgr.DrawPolygons( flm.vecPolygons, pGraphic);
        }
```

if Button: "bViewA" is clicked the panel will get updated

```
private void bViewA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double yMin, yMax, zMin, zMax;
            flm.GetModelExtens(out yMin, out yMax, out zMin, out zMax);
            pgr.SetParametersForViewAll(pGraphic, yMin, yMax, zMin, zMax);

            pGraphic.Invalidate();
        }
```

it calls the Methods
GetModelExtens:

```
public void GetModelExtens(out double ymin,out double ymax,out double zmin,out double zmax)
        {
            ymin = double.MaxValue;
            ymax = -double.MaxValue;
            zmax = -double.MaxValue;
            zmin = double.MaxValue;

            for (int i = 0; i < vecPolygons.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < vecPolygons[i].GetLength(0); j++)
                {
                    
                        if (vecPolygons[i][j, 0] < ymin)
                            ymin = vecPolygons[i][j, 0];
                        if (vecPolygons[i][j, 1] < zmin)
                            zmin = vecPolygons[i][j, 1];
                        if (vecPolygons[i][j, 0]  >ymax)
                            ymax = vecPolygons[i][j, 0];
                        if (vecPolygons[i][j, 1] > zmax)
                            zmax = vecPolygons[i][j, 1];
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

and
setParametersforViewAll

```
public class PolygonGraphics
    {
        double centerX, centerY, scale;
        public PolygonGraphics()
        {
            centerX = 0.0;
            centerY = 0.0;
            scale = 1.0;
        }
public void SetParametersForViewAll ( Panel pGraphic ,double yMin, double yMax, double zMin, double zMax)
        {
            double scaleVert, scaleHorz;
            
            scaleVert = pGraphic.Width/ (yMax-yMin);
            scaleHorz = pGraphic.Height/ (zMax-zMin);

            scale = scaleHorz;
            if (scale > scaleVert)
            { 
                scale = scaleVert;
            }
            scale = scale * 0.9;
            centerX = -yMin * scale + (pGraphic.Width-(yMax-yMin)*scale)* 0.5;
            centerY =  zMax * scale + (pGraphic.Height - (zMax - zMin) * scale) * 0.5;
           
            
        }
```

after invalidation pGraphic_Paint will  trigger DrawPolygons

```
public void DrawPolygons(double[][,] vecPolygons, Panel panel)
        {
            Graphics gr;
            Pen pn = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
        

            gr = panel.CreateGraphics();
            gr.Clear(panel.BackColor);

            double xpx1, ypx1, xpx2, ypx2, ymm1, ymm2, zmm1, zmm2;

            int iLine, iPolygon, index2;

            for (iPolygon = 0; iPolygon < vecPolygons.GetLength(0); iPolygon++)
            {
                for (iLine = 0; iLine < vecPolygons[iPolygon].GetLength(0); iLine++)
                {
                    index2 = (iLine + 1) % vecPolygons[iPolygon].GetLength(0);
                    ymm1 = vecPolygons[iPolygon][iLine, 0];
                    zmm1 = vecPolygons[iPolygon][iLine, 1];

                    ymm2 = vecPolygons[iPolygon][index2, 0];
                    zmm2 = vecPolygons[iPolygon][index2, 1];

                    xpx1 = scale * ymm1 + centerX;
                    ypx1 = -scale * zmm1 + centerY;

                    xpx2 = scale * ymm2 + centerX;
                    ypx2 = -scale * zmm2 + centerY;
                   
                    gr.DrawLine(
                        pn,
                        (float)xpx1,
                        (float)ypx1,
                        (float)xpx2,
                        (float)ypx2);


                }
            }
            
        }
```

Maybe its now easier to understand.
I would be very greatful for an answer

Comment: Hard to help without seeing your code. You can use any number od Draw- and Fill calls, though. So, yes, it probably is easy to do..

Comment: What would you need...the whole code or only the part which is related to the panel painting ?

Comment: Only the part where you paint, hopefully the Paint event!?

Comment: Don't use CreateGraphics.  Do all the painting in the container's paint event using the graphic object provided.

Comment: @LarsTech could you show me what you mean...thank you

Comment: Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object that is bound to a control! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..


You can test the persistance of your graphics by doing a Minimize/Maximize sequence..

The correct way is to keep a list of things to draw and whenever that list changes `Invalidate` the control you draw on. All drawing should be in the `Paint` event, using `e.Graphics` there!

Comment: You can do a `e.Graphics.Clear(yourBackColor)` and then a `e.Graphics.FillPolygon(someBrush, pointArray);`